# React Native createStackNavigator within createSwitchNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to achieve this kind of structure:

```
- Landing page
  - Login button
  - Search button
```

[image]

When I click on login, it takes me to the page no problem:

[image]

However if I click search button, it shows this:

[image]

This is what the landing page looks like only that there is a header from the createStackView.

The content of upon the search button click is supposed to be a page with search landing text.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Landing from "./src/components/Landing";
import Login from "./src/components/Login";

import SearchLanding from "./src/components/Landing";
import SearchByText from "./src/components/SearchByText";
import SearchByScan from "./src/components/SearchByScan";

const AppStack = createSwitchNavigator({
 Landing: { screen: Landing },
 Login: { screen: Login },
 Search: {
  screen: createStackNavigator({
    SearchLanding: { screen: SearchLanding },
    SearchByText: { screen: SearchByText },
    SearchByScan: { screen: SearchByScan }
  })
}
});

class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return <AppStack />;
 }
}

export default App;
```